# Terraform/GCP Error: project: required field is not set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

## Problem

The [google_project](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/project) document says the **project_id** is optional.

> project_id - **(Optional)** The project ID. If it is not provided, the provider project is used.

However, Terraform complains it is required.

gcp.tf

```
data "google_project" "project" {
}

output "project_number" {
  value = data.google_project.project.number
}
```

```
 Error: project: required field is not set
│ 
│   with data.google_project.project,
│   on gcp.tf line 1, in data "google_project" "project":
│    1: data "google_project" "project" {
```

## Question

Please help understand if this is a documentation defect and the argument is mandatory actually.

## Workaround

Set the GOOGLE_PROJECT environment variable.

```
export GOOGLE_PROJECT=...
terraform apply
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your 'Workaround' is functionally equivalent to what the documentation suggests. Namely that the `provider` `project` should be set, i.e.:

```
provider "google" {
  project = "..."
}
```

You don't include your `provider` config but, I assume, it **doesn't** include the default `project` to be used.

So, either|or but, somewhere you need to define the default project.

Otherwise, you should expect to get the error.

Comment: Where would this be set? Eg if i create a `resource`, would the `provider` config you've given be within that resource block? Or outside of it

Comment: @baxx see [Configuring the Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#configuring-the-provider).

Answer (score 0):

The value is needed and somehow it needs to be set, whether in the config file or as a environmental variable.

Might be an issue of outdated documentation.